# How to convert requests.cookiejar to qnetworkcookiejar?

Tags: python, qt, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

Is there a simple way to convert a `cookiejar` from the Python 3 [`requests` library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#cookies) to a [`qnetworkcookiejar`](http://pyqt5doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkcookiejar.html)?

I convert the `cookiejar` from the requests library into a dictionary and then in a `qnetworkcookiejar`. Some cookies are there in multiple versions with different values.

```
def updateCookieJar(self, cookiejar, requested_url):     
    qnetworkcookie_list = []
    cookie_dict = dict_from_cookiejar(cookiejar)
    for cookie in cookie_dict: 
        tmp_cookiejar = QNetworkCookie(cookie, cookie_dict[cookie])
        qnetworkcookie_list.append(tmp_cookiejar)
    qcookiejar = QNetworkCookieJar()
    qcookiejar.setCookiesFromUrl(qnetworkcookie_list, QUrl(requested_url))
    self.networkAccessManager().setCookieJar(qcookiejar)
```

This function is called inside a `Webpage`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `cookiejar` directly instead of dictionary.

```
def updateCookieJar(self, cookiejar, requested_url):     
    qnetworkcookie_list = []

    for cookie in cookiejar:
        tmp_cookiejar = QNetworkCookie(cookie.name, cookie.value)
        qnetworkcookie_list.append(tmp_cookiejar)
    qcookiejar = QNetworkCookieJar()
    qcookiejar.setCookiesFromUrl(qnetworkcookie_list, QUrl(requested_url))
    self.networkAccessManager().setCookieJar(qcookiejar)
```